# Magento 2 setup comporser error?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, composer

Today I create newsite magento2  MAGETWO-40129: M2 GitHub Update (version 1.0.0-beta. When i install composer get

```
ZipArchive::extractTo(): Full extraction path exceed MAXPATHLEN (260)
```

how do fix it. Any thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the [`--prefer-source`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) composer option.
`composer install --prefer-source` instead of `composer install`
`composer update --prefer-source` instead of `composer update`